# What type of gun is the Saint of Killers rocking on The Preacher?

Tags: character, props, preacher

What I'm trying to figure out roughly is the mass of his bullets, and if there's an element with a sufficient atomic weight--they seem to travel at about 70 meters per second, much slower than [standard low-velocity rounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsonic_ammunition), yet were able to blow right through two doors of a police cruiser.

I'm guessing it was a .45 caliber but those chambers look pretty damn big and want to confirm before I start running calculations.

[image: Saint of Killers]

Comment: While the guns in this picture are clearly handguns, there is a hint in the TV show that the Killer is *carrying* a long gun as well (though this is hard to see due to the way it is shot). I don't think we see him explicitly wielding it, though, so this is hard to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comics it's a [**.44 Walker Colt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colt_Walker) and they are *magic* and so **not subject to earthly physics**.

[**Colt Walker at Internet Movie Firearms Database**](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Colt_Walker)

> The Colt Walker, sometimes known as the Walker Colt, was a single-action revolver with a revolving cylinder holding six charges of black powder behind six bullets (typically .44 caliber lead balls). It was designed in 1846 as a collaboration between Captain Samuel Hamilton Walker and American firearms inventor Samuel Colt.

[image]

> The Devil tended to the gunman's wounds, the magical **Walker Colts were cast**, and the man left Hell—but not before gunning down the Devil after the latter insulted him.
>
> [Wikipedia - Saint of Killers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_of_Killers)
>
> The Saint of Killers possesses a pair of Walker Colt revolver pistols, which were bequeathed to him by the Angel of Death, composed from the previous Angel's steel sword and forged in the last fire that burned in Hell, because of the nature of their making, **the guns are demonic in nature**:
>
> - Any shot fired from these guns will always hit its mark, **even piercing modern tank armor to reach the intended target.**

Comment: any info on what substance the bullets are make of?  It's been a while since I read the books, but in the show they appear unstable when Jesse picks one up.

Comment: I just assumed it was still hot...which would make sense in that they are, effectively, from the fires of hell.

Comment: Season 2 is turning out to be pretty awesome in a distinctly Preacher-ey way.  The sound design of that gunfight, where the Saint's rounds sound like artillery shells was spectacular, imo.

Comment: Well yeah...and since the shots come from several hundred yards away it's distinctly outside the range of a vintage handgun....hence *magic*.

Comment: You forgot a the two other magic properties: The hammer will never fall on a empty chamber (*aka* infinite ammo, no reloading), and every shot will be fatal (even against the Devil himself...)

Comment: The bullets are just always fatal bullets, no mention of any (magic!) substance they're made of.  Well, in the comics.  And the show can kiss my arseface.